# Adding content to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm new to Java and actually designing the GUI for an application.
My main is a `JFrame` with 5 buttons and 1 panel which will have the "content", for the first button for example, I've designed a `Jframe` which has a `JTabbedPane`.

Now I would like to know how can I incorporate the content from that frame to the "content" panel when clicking on the button ?

I tried to use `.add` but I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
```

(seems we can't add `Jframe` to `Jpanel`).

I also tried the `setVisible` way but it doesn't meet what I need since it will hide the panel completely and I will get a tiny window with the buttons.

![Jframe content][1]
![Main Jframe with buttons and Jpanel to show the jframe content][2]

The code is generated by netbeans, and I forgot to mention that I did research on adding a Jframe into another Jframe but here isn't my problem at all.

I tried by changing the Jframe by JInternalFrame but clicking on button doesn't do anything.
Button has

```
contentPanel.add(new GestionUtilisateur());
```

So basically when you click on the "Gestion Utilisateur" button for example, you get that JTabbedPane that has to appear in the content area (which is blank here)

Comment: Could you please post the code where you actually add the element to the frame? (and no, you can't add a JFrame to a JPanel, only the other way around)

Comment: Do you want to add a JFrame in a JPanel?? If so, then do not use JFrame , use JInternalFrame.

Comment: check [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) and also post code if you want more help

Comment: [many official samples here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/), and [here is an official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) about panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make and hold references to `JPanels` containing your content. A `JFrame` is really just that, it's a frame (though you can add a single component to it).

You can't add a `JFrame` to a `JPanel`. If you want multiple components to be visible use layouts such as `BorderLayout`, `GridBag`, etc. Check out some of the Swing layout tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should not be putting JFrames inside JPanels. If you have multiple panels you would like to display, depending on something like a button, look in to [LAYOUTS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

In particular, it sounds like a CardLayout would work well for your needs. CardLayouts allow you to swap which panel is displayed in a frame by bringing it to the "front" of a list of panels. This would let you display your JTabbedPane on one button click, then click another to change the content pane.

Answer (score 1):

JFrame can not be added in a JPanel.
use [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)

Answer (score 0):

Content should be designed as JPanel (you can design it with drag&drop just like JFrame) but if you really have to put a JFrame to JPanel for some reason, you can do it by

```
 myJPanel.add(myJFrame.getContentPane());
```

however i would suggest modification of your program.